# js file not loading in ajax returned phtml file magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, phtml

I am returning phtml file content on ajax call in Magento2  its working fine, In the phtml file I am loading **jquery** and mine custom js file `booking`, using below code. A query function running fine, but the custom is not loading because called js function returning `not defined` error -

Here is my code  -

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "booking"   
    ], function(jQuery){
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#load_more").click(function(){
                var c = 1;
                var total_rows = 1;
                $.each($(".location_time"), function(){ 
                    if($(this).css("display") != 'none'){ ++total_rows; };
                    if($(this).css("display") == 'none' && c<=<?php echo $showRows;?>){
                        $(this).css("display","table-row");
                        ++c;
                    }   
                }); 
                if(total_rows == $('#total_rows').val() || c < <?php echo $showRows;?>){
                    $('#load_more').hide();
                }
            });


            bookingTable = $("#booking-table");

            setAddressLocationRows(bookingTable);
        });
    });
```

Error I am getting is  -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setAddressLocationRows is not defined

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Regards
Atul

Comment: where is setAddressLocationRows() set ?

Comment: setAddressLocationRows() is defined in "booking.js" file.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot `function(jQuery, booking){` and you need add change this `booking.setAddressLocationRows(bookingTable);`

```
require([
"jquery",
"booking"   
], function(jQuery, booking){
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#load_more").click(function(){
            var c = 1;
            var total_rows = 1;
            $.each($(".location_time"), function(){ 
                if($(this).css("display") != 'none'){ ++total_rows; };
                if($(this).css("display") == 'none' && c<=<?php echo $showRows;?>){
                    $(this).css("display","table-row");
                    ++c;
                }   
            }); 
            if(total_rows == $('#total_rows').val() || c < <?php echo $showRows;?>){
                $('#load_more').hide();
            }
        });


        bookingTable = $("#booking-table");

        booking.setAddressLocationRows(bookingTable);
    });
});
```